# string won't appear on screen when cout'ed

Tags: c++, string, cout

I'm trying to make a custom DnD character sheet program but I cannot get it to display the name. It has no errors but when it comes to `cout` the name, it just ignores what ever I inputted before as name and gives me nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class playerone {
 public:
  string Name;
  int Level = 1;
  void ready() {
    cout << "ready player one" << endl;
    cin >> Name;
  }
  void info() {
    cout << "name: " << Name;
    cout << endl << "level: " << Level << endl;
  }
};
class option {
 public:
  void create() {
    playerone bo;
    bo.ready();
  }
  void info() {
    playerone bo;
    bo.info();
  }
};

int main() {
  string Name;
  string action;
  cin >> action;
  if (action == "start") {
    option bo;
    bo.create();
  }
  while (action != "stop") {
    cin >> action;
    if (action == "info") {
      option bo;
      bo.info();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two differernt players,one in `option::create` and a different one in `option::info`. You read one and print the info of the other.

I don't see what `option` is good for. The idomatic way to read input and write output is to overload `operator<<` and `operator>>`:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, playerone& p) {
    in >> p.Name;
    // read other members from in
    return in;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const playerone& p) {
    out << p.Name;
    // write other members to out
    return out;
}
```

Now you can read and write a `playerone` like this:

```
int main() {
     playerone p;
     std::cout << "Name: ";
     std::cin >> p;
     std::cout << "Player info: " << p;
}
```

If you want `option` to manage the player, you can do it like this:

```
class option{
    playerone player;
    public:
    void create(){
        std::cin >> player;
    }
    void info(){
        std::cout << player;
    }
};
```

The important bit is that now `create` and `info` use the same `playerone`, which I made a member of `option`.